# zscan not working on redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

**zscan not working on redis server. Its working on redis client.**

```
 Code:
    $redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)

 $redis.zadd("search", 4, "flipkart")
 $redis.zadd("search", 2, "amazon")
 $redis.zadd("search", 1, "cry")

  $redis.zscan("search", 0 )
  -> Redis::CommandError: ERR unknown command 'zscan'

  $redis.zscan("search", 0 , {match: "flip*"})
  -> error
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue.
    Its because of redis server version. Scan was implemented in **redis server 2.8 version**.